# ReactJs force input focus on div button click not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, dom-manipulation

I'm working on a modal in react where I have to click a button outside an input element and focus the input element and change the value. I set the input element to be disabled on default and for the edit button to remove the disabled property and then focus the element. the element is not getting visible focused neither is the disabled property being removed. It looks like it happens in a split second and then returns back to normal because whenever I check if the element is being focused on my console it displays true but It's not being visible focused.
below is my code

```
    EDIT FUNCTION
        const [editState,setEditState] = useState(null)

        const editCatName = (e,id)=>{
            e.stopPropagation();
            setEditState({...editState,id: categories[id].id})
            setActiveButton('editcatname');
            let row = document.querySelectorAll('.cat-row')[id].querySelector('input');

            console.log('row',row)
            row.classList.remove('pointer');
            row.value='Row value set'

            row.hasAttribute('disabled') &&  row.toggleAttribute('disabled')
            row.focus();

            console.log(row.value)
            
        }
        
        const [activeButton,setActiveButton] = useState('newproduct');



    const ProductCategoryModal = ()=>{
        return(

            <div 
             onClick={()=>{setCategoryModal(false)}} 
             className="_modal fixed " style={{zIndex:'100'}} >
        
                <div 
                 onClick={e=>e.stopPropagation()} 
                 className='wytBg boxRad paddBoth sectPad relative'>
        
                    <div>
                        <div className="flexBtw">
        
                            <h3 className="head flexAl">Product Categories</h3>
        
                            <div className='head'> <AiOutlinePlus/> </div>
        
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
        
                    <GridStyle className='nestM' gridp='45% 55%'  gap='0em'>
                        <Scrolldiv className='' measure='300px'>
        
        
                            {
                                categories && categories.length?
                                categories.map((ctg,key)=>  
                                    ctg.name !=='Others' &&  
                                    <div key={key} 
                                     onClick={(e)=>
                                        fixCategoryDetail(ctg.id,e)
                                     } 
                                     className={`cat-row cursor rowws flexBtw ${ key===0 && 'rows- 
                                        top'}`}>
                                        <div>
                                            <input
                                             defaultValue={ctg.name}
                                            //  disabled
                                             style={{maxWidth:'180px'}}
                                             className={'categoryInput pointer '+ key}
                                             onChange={e=>setEditState({
                                                 id:ctg.id,
                                                 value:e.target.value
                                             })}
                                             onBlur={e=>{
                                                    e.target.value=ctg.name
                                                 
                                            }}
                                            />
                                             {/* {ctg.name} */}
                                        </div> 
                
                                        <div className="smallflex hashEdit">
                                            <div> 
                                                <BiEditAlt 
                                                 className='cursor'
                                                 FUNCTION TO FOCUS ELEMENT IS HERE 
                                                 onClick={e=>editCatName(e,key)}
                                                />  
                                            </div>
                                            {
                                                !products.find(prod=>prod.category ===ctg.id) &&
                                                <div className='hash'> <CgClose className='cursor'/> </div>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                
                                    </div>
            
                
                                ):null
                            }
        
        
        
                        </Scrolldiv>
        
                        <Scrolldiv measure='300px' className='secondRow paddBoth'>
                            {
                                categoryDetail.length?                  
                                    <div className=" search  flexC">
                                            <div>
        
                                                <SearchInputBox  
                                                 icon={ <CgSearch style={{width:30}} />}
                                                 padLeft={'10px'}
                                                 className='searchInput smalltxt' 
                                                 inputPadding='0.5em 0.6em'
                                                // onchange={filterByStarts}
                                                 iconPosition 
                                                 summary='Type or search a product'
                                                 options= 
                                    
                                                {products.filter(prod=>
                                                 prod.category===3).map(prod=>prod.name)} 
                                                 inputClassName={'searchInput smalltxt'}
                                                 pad='0'                                       
                                                />
        
                                                <div className="nestM flex">
                                                    <div  measure='150px' > 
                                                        {
                                                            categoryDetail.length?
                                                            categoryDetail.map((ctg,key)=>
                                                                ctg.category !== 3 &&
                                                                <div key={key} className= 
                                                                 {`doubleflex flexBtw smalltxt 
                                                                   itemunits ${key!==0 && 
                                                                   'smallM'} `}>
                                                                    <div>{ctg.name}</div>


                                                                    <div> 
                                                                    <CgClose onClick= 
                                                                    {()=>removeProductFromCategory

                                                                     (ctg.id,ctg.name)} 
                                                                     className='cursor'/> 
</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                    
                                                            ):null
                                                        }
        
                                                        
        
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
        
                                    </div>
                                :null
        
                            }
        
        
                        </Scrolldiv>
        
                    </GridStyle>
                    
                    <div className="section flexC">
                            
                        <button style={{maxWidth:'70%'}} 
                            onClick={()=> 
                            activeButton==='newproduct'?removeProductFromCategory():  
                            activeButton==='addcategory'?createNewCategory():
                            editCategoryName()}
                            className="submit-button category-submit">
                                Update
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
        
        
            </div>
        
    
        )

    }
```

Comment: Hi please, If you do something with react try to replicate the problem with online editor like codesandbox

Comment: It is very simple, what happens is that yow component re re renders so it sets the state back to it's original value of null

Comment: Hi guessed it has to do with re-rendering. But how do I stop that from happening

Comment: Hi, please provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem. You could use https://codesandbox.io/.  Without a example, it is quite difficult to say why the component is rerendering